# Keep the latest of rows for every date-time value present using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, analytics

I have a dataset which looks like this,

```
       DateTime             Value
2019-06-05 12:10:31.467 
2019-06-05 12:27:30.383    13371.6  
2019-06-05 12:49:31.140    14020.4  
2019-06-05 14:58:16.503    14045.5  
2019-06-06 02:58:16.353    14095.8  
2019-06-06 13:21:49.570    14020.4  
2019-06-06 14:51:58.610    14095.8  
2019-06-06 14:58:13.093    13066.3  
2019-06-07 02:58:10.073    13273.4
```

I want the pandas code to get me only the latest value of date-time rows,

```
       DateTime             Value   
2019-06-05 14:58:16.503    14045.5  
2019-06-06 14:58:13.093    13066.3  
2019-06-07 02:58:10.073    13273.4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Amogh Katwe. Please read the following article prior to asking question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use smth like `df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.day).tail(1)` - also group by month/year if you have multiple years etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.date).last().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The grouping is on the date part of *DateTime* and the result from each
group is the last row.

The final part (*reset_index*) is added to delete the (repeated) date
part - the grouping key.

Grouping by *df.DateTime.dt.day* is wrong. It would be obvious if source
data contained dates from different months. In such case all rows from the
first day of each month would be members of the first group, and so on.